# Is it possible to find year of manufacturing for Canon 77D camera from its serial number?

Tags: canon

Planning to buy a Canon 77D from mpb.de website. I know the serial number of camera. Can I approximately find the year of manufacturing from the serial number?

Comment: The year of manufacture doesn't matter. The condition of the camera matters. Canon 77D is from 2017, and the last models were probably manufactured in 2018 or 2019. The age gap between the oldest models and newest models doesn't have any significance here.

Comment: What is the serial number?

Answer (score 1):

The Canon EOS 77D was announced in February of 2017 and began shipping shortly thereafter. So any 77D was not sold until almost mid-2017.

Canon removed the EOS 77D from their catalog in early 2020. It's highly unlikely any were made within a few months of the camera's delisting from the catalog, as Canon would have wanted to reduce existing inventory before it would no longer be offered.

At the earliest, any 77D would not have been made prior to around late 2016, when the initial units shipped for launch would have rolled off the assembly line. At the latest, any 77D would not have been made after mid-2019, and possibly no production runs were made after 2018 or even 2017 if initial sales were significantly lower than Canon's expectations. (Note: Canon makes production runs of each particular model in large enough numbers to stockpile inventory of that model for a few months, then converts the production line tooling to produce a run for a different specific model, then another, and another...)

In 2023 that window from late 2016 until somewhere around mid-2018 or earlier is not enough to make much of a difference. For a used camera which is at least 3+ years old but no older than 6-7 years, the condition due to usage is much more important than the age.

Having said that, serial numbers of Canon bodies do not typically include date codes. What they do include are series/batch codes: that is, when a major revision to any internal part(s) is made, the series number portion of the serial number will advance. This batch code makes it easy for Canon to identify which of several replacement part numbers a camera may need if there is more than one part number for a specific piece of the camera based on which batch it belongs to. But the sequencing of the numbers in the serial number are sort of "scrambled" to make the batch codes less obvious.

---

TL:DR The first two and last four digits of each Canon body appear to be the unique six-digit serial number for that body. The third and fourth digits are almost always the same for every body of the same model, and the fifth through eighth digits are batch codes that seem to be more or less sequential: e.g. 3700, 3800, 3900, etc. for each batch of cameras made during a production run or made without any revisions to internal parts.

---

The details are a bit complicated, but if you're really interested here's a [comment I made on the Canon Rumors Forum](https://www.canonrumors.com/forum/threads/new-canon-eos-r3-orders-may-be-delayed-for-more-than-6-months.41309/post-928189) regarding Canon body serial numbers where I analyze a series of EOS 5D Mark IV serial numbers from about 60 different cameras in an attempt to decipher how the serial numbers are sequenced:

> Recent Canon xD (where 'x' is a single digit number) body serial numbers usually have a 4+4+4 format. The second group of four digits indicate the series (if a part supplier of a significant part is replaced, or a part design is updated they go to the next series number). The first two digits of the first group seem to run sequentially within each second group number. The third and fourth digit of the first group is almost always the same for any particular model number. The third quartet seem to be sequential, but lower numbers (e.g. 1218 or 3257) are much more common than higher ones (e.g. 7942, 5749), at least for xD models (as opposed to higher volume x0D, or xx00D models).

> For the 5DMark IV, for instance, the middle quartet seems to ALWAYS end with two zeros. For the first quartet the third digit is ALMOST ALWAYS "2" and the fourth digit is ALMOST ALWAYS "0"

> Look at used 5D Mark IV bodies on MPB. There are about 60 listed for sale that have legible serial numbers in the product photos. I saw none that did not have "00" for the seventh and eighth digits. I saw four that did not have "20" as the third+fourth digits:

> (spaces added to make the 12 digit numbers more readable as 4+4+4 numbers)

> 1121 5500 0126
> 1280 5500 5498
> 1750 5600 4664
> 3580 3700 4812

> Of the roughly sixty serial numbers, only six end with four digits greater than 5000. Only one has a number higher than 5999 for the last four digits (0220 2100 7942). Greater than 75% (47) of the 60 end with a four digit number below 2800. 40 of the 60 end with a four digit number below 2000.

> The second quartet has one number that shows up over and over again: 3800 (with 19 examples, it's roughly one-third of our sample). A few each make up about 10% of our sample: 2100 (6), 3700 (5), 5300 (4), 5500 (7), 5600 (6), 5700 (8). Other groups show up much less frequently: 2300 (2), 2700 (1), 3000 (1).

> The "3700" series begins with two digits ranging from '35' to '40' (3520 3700 0801, 4020 3700 3836).
> The "3800" series begins with two digits ranging from '45' to '59' (e.g. 4520 3800 0914, 5920 3800 1905).
> The "5300" series ranges from '06' to '08' (0620 5300 2101 , 0820 5300 1811).
> The "5500" series ranges from '11' to '14' (1120 5500 0192, 1420 5500 2705).
> The "5600" series ranges from '15' to '18' (1520 5600 4664, 1820 5600 0509).
> The "5700" series ranges from '05'* to '23' to '30' in our sample (0520 5700 1404, 2320 5700 5134, 3020 5700 0873).
> The "2100" series ranges from '01' to '02' (0120 2100 0256, 0220 2100 7942).

> Both "2300" bodies start with '06'. Notice this is in the same range as the "5300" series.
> The "2700" body starts with '37'. Notice this is in the same range as the "3700" series.
> The "3000" body starts with '59'. Notice this is in the same range as the "3800" series.

> It seems to me that the first two digits and the last four digits combined make up a unique six digit serial number, with the third through eighth digits indicating production runs and/or minor modifications as the model was revised over time.

> *There are some exceptions to the sequence of the first two digits staying within a certain range for each "series", but the only one not noted above with the less used "series" numbers is 0520 5700 1404. That makes me question if I copied the number incorrectly when going through the photos at MPB? If I wrote "0" when I should have written "2", the pattern holds.

> These kinds of patterns seem similar to the differences between many Canon bodies' external serial number and the value recorded in the 'maker notes' section of the EXIF info. The internal number is a combination of the first four characters of the hex resulting from the entire external serial number converted to hex, then the remaining hex characters converted back to decimal. [Example: My 50D's serial number is 1520708485. 1520708485 converted to hex is "5AA42B85". EXIF Info reports the number as 5AA411141. DPP shows it as 1520708485. Irfanview displays it as 1520708485 (5AA411141). Hmm... If one converts 11141 to hex, it's "2B85"! If one then converts hex "5AA42B85" to decimal it's the serial number stamped on the bottom of my camera, 1520708485.]

Comment: I didn't read your answer Michael - much too long for me - but one thing did come to mind in that you didn't mention [check digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit). Now, I've no idea about (nor any great interest in) camera serial numbers, but it wouldn't at all surprise me if manufacturers didn't include a check digit in their serial numbers nowadays. Maybe irrelevant - but worth a mention all the same.

Comment: Some manufacturers of various products do include check codes in serial numbers. VINs for automobiles, for example, include a check digit. I've never seen evidence that Canon includes a check digit in serial numbers. None of the various third party serial number databases that I've encountered for Canon cameras and lenses suggest such a thing, either. I worked in banking operations back in the 1980s, so I'm well acquainted with check digits. Every transit routing number and almost every account number in the U.S. includes them, as do credit card numbers.

Comment: It seems more likely that Canon's hybrid hex/decimal "internal serial number" is the route they've chosen to guard against serial numbers being altered/counterfeited. If you read the answer above, you'll see that it's fairly sophisticated, which is why the answer is so long.